# Expected Primary Expression (Solidity)

Tags: mapping, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am creating a simple smart contract, however, I am getting an error on my last function ("ViewNotes") stating that the compiler was "Expected Primary Expression"? Can I not check the value at a mapping (of address => string) against the value *0* ?

My code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract Logistics{

address public owner;
mapping(address => string) notes;

modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
}

constructor(address genesis) public {
   owner = genesis;
}

function sign(string signedNote) public onlyOwner{
        notes[owner] = signedNote; //gaurenteed that msg.sender == owner
}

function transferOwnership(address nuOwner) onlyOwner {
    owner = nuOwner;
}

function viewNotes(address participant) public returns(string){ // signed note on success nothing on fail
    if(notes[participant] !== 0){
        return (notes(participant));   
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple issues. The primary issue is that you misspelled `!=`. (You have an extra equals sign. `!==` is an operator in JavaScript, but not in Solidity.)

Once you fix that, you'll find that you can't compare a `string` to the number `0`. You probably want to check the string's length? You'll need to cast to `bytes` to do that:

```
function viewNotes(address participant) public returns (string) {
    if (bytes(notes[participant]).length != 0) {
        return notes[participant];
    }
}
```

That said, I believe this is probably equivalent to just:

```
function viewNotes(address participant) public returns (string) {
    return notes[participant];
}
```

And you could instead just make `notes` `public`:

```
mapping(address => string) public notes;
```

That way, Solidity will generate a getter function for you, and people can just call `notes(addr)`, making `viewNotes` redundant.

Fixing up a couple other warnings, getting rid of the modifier in favor of a direct ownership check, and assigning initial ownership to the deployer, here's my take on the contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Logistics{
    address public owner = msg.sender;
    mapping(address => string) public notes;

    function sign(string note) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        notes[owner] = note;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        owner = newOwner;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Do you know how I could use metamask to let users 'sign into' my UI and then sign and transfer the notes-ledger in my application if they are the current owner? I am a little confused on how that would work, or if its even possible?

Comment: I guess I am a little confused on how to integrate metmask through web3.js in this case